# Multi column list with embed breaks design when page is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using ul li to embed multiple integrative visual on a page with embed. this is done with css and responsive feature works fine unless we resize page, once page is resized graphics doesnt resize unless page is not refreshed.

How can i fix this so that it resizes as per screen size without refreshing as this happens on this [link](https://blog.datawrapper.de/weekly-chart-covid19-excess-mortality/)

Codepen [example](https://codepen.io/Kash-Souq/pen/wvYbQYw?editors=1100)

```
/* container */
.responsive-three-column-grid {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

/* columns */
.responsive-three-column-grid > li {
    padding:15px;
}

/* tablet breakpoint */
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .responsive-three-column-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}



<ul class="responsive-three-column-grid">
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/gFYSX/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/gFYSX/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/UMD6G/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/UMD6G/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/JjEih/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/JjEih/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/Ph5Jv/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/Ph5Jv/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/t9xIQ/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/t9xIQ/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/C00z8/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/C00z8/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/fjRjS/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/fjRjS/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/NIV7c/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/NIV7c/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/bLO1P/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/bLO1P/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/4J2a5/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/4J2a5/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/7SUzk/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/7SUzk/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" defer src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/U72bR/embed.js?v=1" charset="utf-8"></script><noscript><img src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/U72bR/full.png" alt="" /></noscript>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```